# Is $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x-y}$ continuous at $f(0,0)$?

Tags: continuity

If it is, would it be the same reasoning that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\Bbb R_{\geq 0} \ni t \mapsto \sqrt{t} \in \Bbb R$ is continuous, and so is the map $$\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \geq y\} \ni (x,y) \mapsto x-y \in \Bbb R.$$Your map $f$ is the composite of these two continuous maps, hence also continuous.

Comment: Yes, but you've specified a domain that the OP did not.

Comment: True, but I'm thinking that this is probably an exercise in an early multivariable calculus course where people usually get sloppy and assume that the domain is the largest possible (not complex) :P

Answer (score 0):

Let $D:=\{(x,y):x \ge y\}$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then put $ \delta=\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$. For $(x,y) \in D$ with $||(x,y)-(0,0)||_2 < \delta$ we have:

$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|^2=x-y=|x-y| \le |x|+|y| \le 2 ||(x,y)|| <2 \delta = \epsilon^2$,

hence

$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| < \epsilon$.